Get Program Name property of Word file as shown in Windows Explorer
I want to obtain the "Program Name" property for Microsoft Word files.
This property is visible in Windows Explorer.

I tried to obtain all properties of a file with the following code:
Sub Property_List()
    Dim Folder_Path as String
    Dim File_Name as String
    Dim vShell as New Shell32.Shell
    Dim vRep as Shell32.Folder
    Dim vFich as Shell32.FolderItem
    Dim aPropName() as String
    Dim i as Integer
    Folder_Path = ".............."
    File_Name = ".................doc"
    Set vShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set vRep = vShell.NameSpace(Folder_Path)
    Set vFich = vRep.Items.Item(File_Name)
    For i = 1 to 1000
        Redim Preserve aPropName(i)
        aPropName(i) = Format(i, "000:") & vRep.GetDetailsOf(vFich, i)
        If Len(vRep.GetDetailsOf(vFich, i) = 0 then
            ReDim Preserve aPropName(i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
     Next i
    Dim vFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim MyFile
    Set vFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set MyFile = vFSO.CreateTextFile(Folder_Path & "\Prop List-" & File_Name & ".txt", true)
    MyFile.Close
    Set vFSO = Nothing
    Set MyFile = Nothing
    Set vFich = Nothing
    Set vShell = Nothing
    Set vRep = Nothing
End Sub

I get a text file with 36 properties. I am not getting "Program Name".
This solution based on this StackOverflow by Szwr.

This example works for me:
Sub Tester()
    Dim fileInfo As Object    

    Set fileInfo = GetFileAttributes("C:\Temp\blah.docx")
    
    If fileInfo.Exists("Program Name") Then
        Debug.Print fileInfo("Program name")
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not found"
    End If
End Sub


'Add a reference: Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation
Function GetFileAttributes(FilePath As String) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim objShell As Shell32.Shell, objFolder As Shell32.Folder
    Dim objFolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem, i As Long
    Dim strFileName As String, aName As String, aValue As String, strPath As String
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case insensitive
    strFileName = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") + 1)
    strPath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(strFileName) - 1)
    
    Set objShell = New Shell
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strPath)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strFileName)
        
    For i = 0 To 255
        aName = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(Null, i)
        aValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i)
        'list only the attributes with a value:
        If Len(aValue) > 0 Then
            dict.Add aName, aValue
            'Debug.Print i & " - " & aName & ": " & aValue
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetFileAttributes = dict
End Function


Dear Tim Thanks a lot for your guidance and the sample code. The code is working correctly as per my requirement. Request, kindly guide what below code means in the sample code aName = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
aValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i

Slight edit above: aName = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(Null, i) retreives the column name for the file's i'th attribute; objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i) retreives the value of that attribute.

Thanks a lot for the guidance. Pl advise how to flag as "Accepted", your reply definitively answered my question.

There should be a "tick" or "check" next to my answer, which you can click to flag as Accepted.
